Make PyCharm One Dark similar to VS Code One Dark
I am using the same theme for both VS Code and PyCharm: One Dark. Even the same font. I've even activated italics in PyCharm for the required keywords like class, def, for, if, return. But still the difference is still visible, as can be seen in the images below. Is there a way of bridging this difference?

This is VS Code. (Above pic)

This is PyCharm.

the file parsers of VSC and PyCharm see self very different, keyword or variable, self is a variable, background color (editor) is different
